# Finding the power dissipation in a wye-connection given resistors

Tags: power, three-phase, power-dissipation

The problem that I'm attempting to solve is the following:

> Three 1000 Ω resistors are connected in Y to a 200-Vac line. The power dissipation of the Y combination would be _____W.
>
> a. 42
>
> b. 41
>
> c. 40
>
> d. 39

What I assume is that the resistors act as the impedances. So, Z_y = 1000 ohm. Now, using S = 3(I^2)Z_y leads me to 120 W. I get the current from dividing 200 and 1000. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Now, using S = 3(I^2)Z_y leads me to 120 W. I get the current from
> dividing 200 and 1000. Where did I go wrong?*

You incorrectly used the line voltage (200) when it should be the phase voltage. If the resistors were in delta formation you'd use the line voltage but, they are in Y or star formation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Andy aka. For calculating line current, phase voltage is to be found first. Impedance is given. From this, you can calculate the line current which is the same as phase current in Y network. Power is calculated as sqrt(3).(V_L).(I_L).(power factor).
Option C will be the answer.